# How to get individual letters in a string

Tags: java

I am so confused on how to search individual letters (specific vowels) within the the array of my string.

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Word {
    private String word;
    private static String vowels = "AEIOUaeiou";   //only one

    public Word() {
        String vow = "";
        vowels = vow;
    }

    public Word(String wrd) {
        word=wrd;
    }

    public void setWord(String wrd) {
    }

    public int getNumVowels(String[] ray, String vowels) {
        int count=0;
        for(String item : ray) {
            if() {
                count = count + 1;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public int getLength(String[] ray) {
        return 0;
    }

    public String toString(String[] ray) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

This is the runner. How do I getNumVowels to work by searching for an individual letter by the input?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class WordRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String alpha="";
        String [] ray = new String[4];
        ray[0] ="Polo";
        ray[1] ="Crazy";
        ray[2] ="Abracadabra";
        ray[3] ="Awesome";

       out.println(Arrays.toString(ray));
       out.println("Number of vowels: " + Arrays.getNumVowels(ray));  
       out.println("Length of the word: " + Arrays.getLength(ray));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors in your code...

You're calling `Arrays` methods which does not exists...

```
out.println("Number of vowels: "+ Arrays.getNumVowels(ray));  
out.println("Length of the word: "+ Arrays.getLength(ray));
```

Modify `Word` class (you put a lot of innecessary stuff):

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Word
{
    private static String vowels = "AEIOUaeiou";   //only one


    public static int getNumVowels(String word)
    {
        int count=0;
        for (int i=0; i < word.length(); i++)
        {
            // check if selected char is a vowel
            if (vowels.contains(word.charAt(i) + ""))
            {
                count ++; // same as count = count + 1
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

}
```

Then to call the method, as it is static:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
     System.out.println("Number of vowels of Polo: "+ Word.getNumVowels("Polo"));   
     //Output:
     //         Number of vowels of Polo: 2

     // or execute like this:
     String a = "Polo";
     int vowels = Word.getNumVowels(a);
     System.out.printlm("Number of vowels of Polo: "+ vowels);
     //Output:
     //         Number of vowels of Polo: 2
}
```

**UPDATE**: if you want your word class count vowels in an array, simply use already existing method.

Inside `Word` class add an overload of the existing method that receives an array and use the old one:

```
// overload: same method name, but different arguments!!!
public static int getNumVowels(String[] array)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < array.lenght; i ++){
        // use existing method to save code!! 
        count += getNumVowels(array[i]);
    }

    return count;
}
```

And use it like:

```
String [] ray = new String[4];
ray[0] ="Polo";
ray[1] ="Crazy";
ray[2] ="Abracadabra";
ray[3] ="Awesome";


int vowels = Word.getNumVowels(ray);  // count vowels in ALL array words...
```

Comment: I used the method, however now it says contains is not applicable for the statement...

Comment: True, sorry Use `if (vowels.contains(word.charAt(i)+""))` to transform char to string

Comment: Great to hear that! :) As this is your first question in StackOverflor, you have to know if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. **Of course, there is no obligation to do this.**

Answer (score 0):

You can get the char array from the string and loop over it looking for the required vowel (if you want to count how many times a single vowel appears, then there's no need to pass a string, you can simply use a char).

```
public int getNumVowels(String[] ray, char vowel) {
    int count=0;
    for(String s: ray)
    {
        char[] array = s.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
            if(array[i] == vowel) {
                count = count + 1;
            }
        }


    }
    return count;
}
```

You need the `s.toLowerCase()` only if you want the search to be case insensitive (because for example 'a' is different from 'A').

Answer (score -1):

Straightforward way:

```
String vowels = "AEIOUaeiou";
    int count = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
    {
        if (vowels.contains(str.charAt(i) + ""))
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
```

Comment: he does not want to count ALL vowels, but only how many times a specific vowel appears